# Web API nested resource failing under IIS8

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, iis-8

I have a fairly straight-forward Web API project that has the following route under the Default route in WebApiConfig.cs:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "ChildApi",
   routeTemplate: "api/{parentController}/{parentId}/{controller}/{id}",
   defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

This works fine running under the VS2012 development server and navigating to my test URI (`/api/team/1/entries/2013-04-19`) returns the correct results. Once I publish this and attempt to access the same URI using IIS8, I receive the following 404 error:

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Most likely causes:
The directory or file specified does not exist on the Web server.
The URL contains a typographical error.
A custom filter or module, such as URLScan, restricts access to the file.

Things you can try:
Create the content on the Web server.
Review the browser URL.
Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code and see which module is calling SetStatus. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click here.

Detailed Error Information:
Module     IIS Web Core
Notification       MapRequestHandler
Handler    StaticFile
Error Code     0x80070002
```

All non-nested routes (e.g. `/api/team/1`) work fine, but it seems that this particular route is being interpreted as a static file and IIS is attempting to serve it up as such? Has anyone else seen/resolved this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so this is embarrassing...

I set my route up in WebApiConfig.cs like so:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "ChildApi",
   routeTemplate: "api/{parentController}/{parentId}/{controller}/{id}",
   defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

I then proceeded to add my published project to IIS under the application name "api". This (now obviously) means that the URL I should have used is `/api/api/team/1/entries/2013-04-19`.

Changing my route as follows as now resolved my issue:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "ChildApi",
   routeTemplate: "{parentController}/{parentId}/{controller}/{id}",
   defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

I think the confusion was caused by the fact that this route works fine in debug mode (as if the VS2012 development server strips the first `/api` from the URL).